How to add a custom field into Swagger?
enter image description here
Ah, My English is bad, I think you can understand the meaning through the picture.
Thanks a lot.
this is a part of my pom
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    </dependency>

